# Are there any flight price search engines with baggage allowance included?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, luggage, flight-search-engines

I am looking for a flight search engine that includes a luggage calculator in the price. I recently booked a trip and had the choice between two carriers at the time, and not feeling very stupid I chose the cheaper one.

The crux is that after I had paid I found out that the more expensive airline had vastly different rules for baggage. In fact it allowed twice the amount of baggage without extra charge.

After having found the price for extra luggage very extreme I had already decided I will send the extra baggage as separate freight, because the speed is not important. But of course had I known this from the start I could have saved myself a lot of work and money.

I am aware that this information can be found on respective carrier website, but even within a single company it can differ from route to route. Would be handy if I didn't have to try and calculate it all myself.

So my question is simply, is there any flight search engine/price comparison site where I can also enter my total baggage needs to have it included in the price comparison between carriers?

Comment: **Checked or carry-on?** International intercontinental, short-range, domestic (which routes)? Only for 0-1 checked bags? (fees for 2nd checked bag can be higher)? Do you need to see the weight limit for checked bag? (these can vary a lot, by carrier, ticket class and route). Also for 1 carry-on baggage? (yes some low-budget airlines charge for that too, and/or impose severe size and weight limits, depending on class of ticket)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Beat That Flight does this (disclaimer: I run it)

Example: [LAX to SFO](https://bookings.beatthatflight.com.au/flights/lax2508sfo1)

on the left of the screen, you can select without baggage, or with luggage and carry-on.

[image]

Older answer: Sort of.  You could use [FlightFox](http://flightfox.com/) which allows you to specify your terms (date, cities, etc) and one of the options is whether or not you have baggage.  It's up to the experts on the site then to find you the cheapest WITH baggage.

I did this recently for several flights around NZ/Aus, where  there are airlines like Virgin or Jetstar, all of whom charge extra for baggage, so look cheap at first.  Each of the experts that submitted flights to me all correctly took this into account, and specified that they'd done so.  So it seems pretty reliable.  Of course, being done by humans and not computer, [*caveat emptor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor) and all that, you should still double check yourself.

**note** - around this time I actually joined Flightfox as an expert 'flight hunter'.

Comment: Well then, FlightFox it is! I need to remember to remember to post a new answer to this in the future when someone does include this feature in a regular search engine heh :D

Comment: Did you use to work for FlightFox?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm ages ago, yes, as one of their 'experts'.  Take this to [chat] though if you want to ask more :)

Comment: you have to pay for FlightFox where you book with them or not.

Comment: How to do a one-way flight on `Beat That Flight`?

Comment: @TomHale The example above is one way.  Otherwise go to https://bookings.beatthatflight.com.au/ and enter your flight, and then just leave out a return date.

Answer (score 9):

This question is five years old, so the "state of the art" may have advanced significantly for lots of engines, but I've noticed that [at least Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/flights) allows you to specify how much baggage you have. Unfortunately, it doesn't mention in-flight meals, which is another way [they can slug you](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24968/are-airlines-legally-obligated-to-feed-passengers-without-charging).

[Example link to a query](https://www.kayak.com/flights/SYD-OSA/2019-10-11)

Note: As of 2019 this feature works on Kayak.com, but not on some of their other international sites.

[image]

Comment: Fee Calculator shows only Payment fees, not Baggage fees, for me.

Comment: @gerrit this no longer works on the Australian website, but works on the .com version. Weirdly in July 2017 it worked on the Australian site, but not on the American one :)

Comment: I'm trying the .com version right now, from Korea. While it looks like it works, when I actually get to the site and select my luggage needs and enter stuff into all the compulsory fields, I finally find out the actual price is still about double the price the Kayak told me it found )-:

Comment: I've noticed that _sometimes_ when you change the bags setting, Kayak fails to update the price.  Another irritation to watch out for is that when you change dates or airports or times, or sort criteria, Kayak clears the bags settings back to zero.

Comment: Note that it says `Baggage per passenger`, so you can't have 2 adults and 1 checked bag.  For that, see the answer for kiwi.com.

Answer (score 2):

[Kiwi.com](https://www.kiwi.com/deep?affilid=tomhale) (formerly skypicker.com) allow filtering searches by bags:

1. Click on these icons above the destination:

[image: Click here]

2. Then you'll see:

[image: Bag search]

This is one of the only options that allows you to have say 2 adults and 1 checked bag.  Kayak (for example) only allows searching "Baggage per passenger".

Answer (score 1):

Momondo.com allows searching for bags, but it's per-passenger: you can't do 2 people with one checked bag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you asked for, but makes searching a little easier: on [Fareboom](http://www.fareboom.com/) when you go into details of a specific result, you can click and have it show something like: Free Baggage: 20 kg

Doesn't allow to enter your luggage mass in the search form, but at least you don't have to visit each carrier website to find out.

Comment: Fareboom was new to me, so I tried it.  The form asks for "city or country" but if I put in Spain to USA, the pop-up is "please select a valid airport or city."  Put in two airports, maximum radius, and month of June, and I get "those airports don't qualify for the whole month option."

Comment: @WGroleau: so just select sample cities like MAD-JFK or whatever, as a guideline, to see the numbers.

Comment: No thanks.  Some of the others are starting to figure in rates with bags.