# Are airlines legally obligated to feed passengers without charging?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, food-and-drink, jetstar

Is there any duration and/or distance of flight beyond which airlines are legally obliged to feed passengers without charging them for it? If so, what is the limit?

In case jurisdictions matter, I'm flying from Australia to Japan with Jetstar, a presumably Australian airline.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was flying from Singapore to New Zealand (11 hours). Jetstar will not feed you without additional charge. This is company policy. They won't even bring you tea or coffee without charging. In addition, economy class is creepily cold. Bring some warm clothes.

In business class meals included in cost of flight ticked. In economy class you must [pre-purchase](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/what-we-offer/in-flight/food-and-drinks.) it.

Comment: I can confirm that (Singapore - Gold Coast, 8 hours) I'd also recommend to take a cup, there are water dispensers near the toilet doors, and I'm not sure if they give you one.

Comment: There is no law.  Airlines can essentially do what they like.  I once heard a rumor that some airline wanted to charge for using the WC.  Imagine that on a long haul flight

Comment: That was good old Ryanair in the UK, was a suggestion in a staff competition to find new ways to get money off customers, it was a bit too far, even for them.

Comment: @MarkChapman I sometimes wonder if all those rumours about things Ryanair supposedly plans to do to squeeze customers aren't the result of well executed smear campaigns by competitors... Few times I've seen their CEO on television about plans those were reasonable (like asking permission to remove the galleys as they're not offering in flight service anyway so it's dead weight).

Comment: Actually it was the CEO I heard talking about it, he's also seemingly said a few racy things on twitter, I think he likee to stir up controversy as free publicity.

Comment: @MarkChapman - yes, and don't forget his "blowjobs for people in first class" comment. Which shows how seriously he takes himself. (He's also said he's underpaid, relative to other airline bosses. But no one else would hire him, so there's nothing he can do.)

Comment: @jwenting: Well, when he's on TV in front of the public, it makes sense that he'd talk about the reasonable stuff rather than the not-so-reasonable stuff.

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no regulation that obliges airlines to provide free food during the normal operation of flights.

However, [in the EU they *do* have to](http://www.airpassengerrights.eu/en/flight-delay.html) provide free "meals and refreshments in a reasonable relation to the waiting time" when a flight is delayed by more than two to four hours (depending on the length of the flight).

Comment: So do railways.  In my experience, *meals and refreshments* might be interpreted widely...

Comment: The "in the EU they do have to..." part is mostly theoretical, though. In practice (seen at Arlanda 2 years ago), "respectable" airlines like LH will simply cancel all flights for 48 hours and have people stand in line for 6 hours, then try to trick them into accepting that they must come back the next day for "stand by list", and when you refuse try to trick you into missing your flight by purposely telling you a check-in time the next morning which makes it impossible to reach the gate (if you're stupid enough to believe them). All without as much as one bite or a drop of water.

Comment: Similar for BA, which will just close all check-ins and show you the middle finger, telling you to call an extra expensive service number (where you're told that you can get hotel refunded if you checked in -- which of course they won't let you do). Seen in Heathrow 3 years ago.

Comment: @Damon both of which assume the delay is known before passengers check in, in which case the airline has no requirement to compensate you at all except if you have ongoing connections with them which they have to reschedule (and they are likely required to put you in a hotel if the delay is overnight). Passengers who're checked in and waiting will have to be catered for, though airlines often find ways around it. Like Transavia at Schiphol several years ago handing out 1 Euro vouchers when the cheapest option in the restaurant was closer to 10 Euro.

Comment: <ctd> or KLM putting us in a hotel overnight during a 12 hour delay in London and not supplying vouchers for the hotel bar until after the bar had closed, then giving us vouchers for a breakfast in the hotel but we had to leave the hotel to catch our flight before the restaurant opened.

Comment: @jwenting I don't think you can really complain that KLM didn't give you free booze.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm talking about dinner, breakfast, even a glass of water. We got nothing at all.

Comment: @jwenting Dinner, fair complaint. Breakfast, hard to say but they tried (ineffectively) and it sounds like you'd have had difficulties getting breakfast even if you'd been scheduled on that flight. Glass of water, oh, come on! Hotel room? Bathroom? Tap?

Comment: @DavidRicherby we had been scheduled for an evening flight, were put on a morning flight instead, with no compensation, no food or drinks of any kind provided by the airline. They gave us vouchers they knew in advance we'd not be able to use. They could have given us vouchers for an airport lounge instead for example, which were open for breakfast and there was time once we got there. But instead they gave us vouchers for the hotel restaurant which opened at 7:30 (was even printed on the vouchers) and then told us our bus would pick us up at 6:30...

Answer (score 2):

The terms and conditions for a Qantas flight I'm on explicitly mentions that JetStar usually doesn't supply food and beverage as an inclusion. This suggests that they aren't merely bluffing about not supplying it:

> **Jetstar (JQ) & Jetstar Asia (3K) Flights - Onboard Inclusions/Exclusions**
>   Food, beverages and entertainment are not
>   included in most Jetstar fares.