# How to seat family of seven together on long-haul flight?

Tags: air-travel, seating, american-airlines

My family and I are flying to New Zealand (AKL) from the USA (LAX) in just over a week.  We booked 7 seats (in a single booking), but when I check the American Airlines website it says we don't have seats assigned, and recommends I select seats.  The 7 of us are Mum and Dad (my wife and I), 4 kids (16, 14, 13, 5 years old), and our friend.

When I go to select seats there is only two areas that have a block of enough open seats for 7 people to at least sit close together, however more than half of these seats cost (approx $86-$120 USD each).

Now we don't care where on the plane we sit, we just want to sit together as a family, but can't afford to pay another ~$500 USD to select specific seats.

Are we likely to be seated together anyway if we check-in together?  Or are we just going to get random open seats?

Our flight back is on United and we were able to select seats together on the United website without incurring any extra charge.

Here is a screenshot of some of the available seats, to show what we've got to work with currently.

[image]

Comment: You’ll find you’ll have more options if you break into a group of four and a group of three rather than an unbreakable group of seven.

Comment: @RoboKaren I'm not sure I understand, are you saying book separate groups, or just try to select separate blocks of seats?  We're happy to sit in two groups (our friend with the 3 teens, my wife and I with the 5yo), however the seats even with this type of grouping are not available.  The only "free" seats available are middle seats.  Where there are a group together, the window/aisle seats, either side of the free middle seat, cost extra.

Comment: @RoboKaren I have added a screenshot to highlight the dilemma

Comment: @Midavalo If nothing opens up, just choose the best you can and then call the airline. If they won’t accommodate you check in early. The check in agents are human and will do their best to accommodate you. Don’t pay that $500 to select seats now airlines are getting too greedy, that money could be put to better use. Unless of course it peanuts to you.

Comment: 86 dollars for seat selection in Economy class?! You're being ripped off.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn The seats that are marked as unavailable are unavailable.  Most airlines now days will reserve select seats for high status or otherwise important passengers, and charge others for them.  It's not extortion, it's just the current charging model used by most airlines.

Comment: @Doc That’s your opinion. A whole bunch of airline fees introduced in the past few years are extortion plain and simple. It’s my opinion, as well as that held by millions of other people.

Comment: Further reading: [Why You Should Never Pay To Select Seats](https://flytrippers.com/never-pay-select-seats/). Also (UK): [Airlines to be investigated over charging for allocated seats](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/2018/02/airlines-to-be-investigated-over-charging-extra-for-allocated-seats-/)

Comment: @MrWhite's link is superb (check in online precisely 24hr45m before, immediately choose your seat assignments online). Also be aware that the exact same flight sold via codeshare can have different pricing models for seats (e.g. AA, BA, Cathay, JAL). Anyway don't pay those. Also, to understand your hard constraints, strictly only your 5yo really needs to sit beside you, right; everything else is nice-to-have.

Comment: I don't understand how you get to $500. What I would do is get plenty of aisle so people can swap seats within the group often +  at least one window seat to entertain the young. That is, the two seats to the right of the right hand aisle in rows 25, 26, 27, plus one of the window seats in 25/26 (if it's a boeing 787 you don't want more than 1 because they are cramped and the electronic windows don't dim properly.) That's 3 free and 4 paid seats, a total of $86x4=$344. Or instead of the window seat buy the seat in row 28. That gives your group FOUR chances of sitting next to an unoccupied seat

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn the opposing view is also held by millions. Bottom line is that the comments are not the place to discuss it, or make political declarations like that. You can include it in an answer if you like, but comments are for clarification from the OP or suggestions for improving the question.

Comment: Just as a warning, there are some systems (e.g. Ryanair) that will explicitly, intentionally scatter your group across the plane as the default free check-in option. Choosing to be seated as you want (e.g. together) is an extra service with an extra fee for them, and they're ensuring that customers who decline to buy it don't simply get given that extra for free.

Comment: You might want to consider letting the kids sit by themselves, not to far (an aisle or two) from the parents. On our last cross-atlantic flight my nine year old sat by herself a good five or six aisles away, and had lovely conversations with the adults near her. I feel that experience did more for her development than the entire rest of the trip did.

Comment: @Doc I've never used an American carrier, but I do fly with Skyteam (aside from Delta) on a regular basis (50 flights per year) and some non-Skyteam a few times per year, and I have never seen that kind of seat selection charging system. There are usually some seats that have an extra cost (order of 20-50 dollars), e.g. the front-row seats with extra legroom or some seats that are only two in a row while normal is three, but I have never seen that all window/aisle seats cost extra, and I've never seen as high fees as 86 dollars within economy for the selection. This is a rip-off. Period.

Comment: @dotancohen that can work out nicely, but it is also very likely to make the passengers sitting with the child uncomfortable. Not everyone would talk with the child, and of course, not all children would talk with strangers. I would strongly recommend against it, unless the child is already in its teens.

Comment: @bjorn It's a completely optional fee, who's main purpose is actually to reserve seats for the airlines more valuable clients (frequent flyers and select corporate customers) who get to select these seats for free.  At time of check-in, all seats are available for selection for free.Many European airlines also reserve seats for such clients, however they do not give the option to purchase them at all to others - at least this way you have the choice! Also, it IS only the first few rows that have this pricing - those further back are free (but, in this case, apparently already taken)

Comment: @Doc, okay, I thought it was that pricing for all the rows in the plane. In that case I must say that OP could have thought about this earlier and selected the free seats, or if he booked last-minute, realize that this kind of issues might arise. Anyway, I would still call them and see if the youngest child can be seated with a parent, but obviously it is not reasonable to expect the whole group of 7 to be seated together for free. Someone on board would probably also help(I do that sometimes if they have a good reason, but I fly a lot so I get free seat selection)

Comment: At least the kids should be grouped together with the adults by the airline without additional costs, otherwise that would be quite indecent behavior, I'd say. Say at most three groups: Mom + two kids, dad + two kids, friend.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you check in, chances are they'll try and seat you together or as near as possible. Under 16s usually are considered as minors, so they cannot travel unaccompanied just like someone already mentioned. Imagine a mum travelling with a 3 and a 5 YO. They would "have" to be seated near their mum...

Comment: They can absolutely travel unaccompanied from gate to gate. See for example [United's policy](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/specialneeds/minors/default.aspx) (which says they will escort the child to and from the gate, but doesn't mention anyone flying with the child). If they're willing to fly the child with no parent anywhere on the plane, they will surely be willing to fly the child with a parent in another row.

Comment: Simply not true these days. They will try to accomodate kids under 5, but the rest is "pay extra to sit together"

Comment: @Kevin United's unaccompanied minor service includes "Flight attendants will check in with your child periodically throughout the flight," and this extra attention from flight attendants is part of what the extra $150 pays for.  Plus in my fairly extensive experience children are far better behaved when separated from their parents.  The last thing the airline wants is a child in row 12 screaming for a parent in row 26.

Comment: Europe's rules are different, but I'd have to find a link to provide proof.

Comment: This is indeed what happened - when we checked in (online) it gave us a group of seats in a block almost together (5 in one row, two in the row in front). We were able to switch one seat so there were 3 in one and 4 in the other (gave up an aisle seat for middle seat)

Answer (score 29):

Your best bet is to try to phone in and get a sympathetic agent to waive the fees and seat you. But it's entirely discretionary, you have no right to claim these seats, it's just if they're feeling nice or generous. Or try to get some  seats when you check in when some of them are released, but there’s no guarantee to this strategy.

Once you get on the plane, it's unlikely you'll get people to move. Travel blogs are full of complaints from single travelers who paid the US$100+ to get an aisle seat, who are then asked by families to move to an aisle seat so that they can sit together.

There is unanimity that this is not a fair request unless they are being moved to an equivalent aisle seat or bumped up in service class (from an aisle in economy to a middle seat in business or economy plus), or that they are being paid a cash amount that satisfies them (not necessarily the cash amount they paid for the initial aisle seat placement).

Indeed, cabin attendants are loathe to force anyone to move unless there is an equivalent or better seat. So the family only has the power of pleading. And people are increasingly not moving, because they paid that $100 for that aisle seat.

The reality is that aisle seats are a desirable "product" and the airline is free (absent legislation passed prohibiting it; a moral outcry from its customers; or customers shifting to companies without these policies) to price its product in a way that gets maximal profit. Unbundling services to reduce the base cost is now common amongst carriers and it's what we get by sorting by base price.

I really hate paying the $100 for my own singleton travel but I do so (or fly on an airline or in a class that allows for aisle seating).  May I ask -- in all bluntness -- why you feel entitled to get a product for free that others have to pay for?  If I have wide shoulders or long legs that make sitting in middle-seats uncomfortable, should I get an aisle seat for free?   Should couples or business travelers who want to sit together also be able to petition for a waiver of the aisle-seat charge?

The one exception I could see would be a waiver for children under 12 to sit next to an adult but that only applies to one of your four children.

Comment: To downvoters: I think this type of surcharge is obnoxious  but it's how some airplanes play the pricing game. They reduce the base airline ticket prices by a certain amount and then charge a certain amount more for the "upgrade." This way they get a net  profit from those who pay, and those who don't pay get a discount.  They're doing this "unbundling" with other things like meals and luggage. If you don't like this game, fly with another company who doesn't play it or in a class where it doesn't apply.

Comment: Explicitly pricing favorable seats also has the advantage of making sure everyone who wants a good seat can get one at any time for a surcharge. Without surcharges it becomes a game of musical chairs, where people who book earliest get to pick the best seats, which is likewise irritating.

Comment: And since everyone is sorting by price, the unbundled companies get to appear at the top of the flight search matrix.... :-(

Comment: There are now search engines which handle that as well :) [See a related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/are-there-any-flight-price-search-engines-with-baggage-allowance-included)

Comment: @RoboKaren I wasn't requesting special treatment or saying I'm entitled to anything.  I selected seats while booking (through a third-party) and didn't get those seats.  I was surprised to find I had to pay for seats, if we wanted to sit together, when I got onto the AA website, so my question was around whether it's likely that we would be seated together since there were no allocated seats showing.  Additionally, I wouldn't call it getting "something for free..." when I have already paid a lot of money for those 7 seats to start with.

Comment: @RoboKaren  I have never had to pay for seat selection on a long-haul flight before (I had seen the option on US and other domestic flights but never used it).  If I had known beforehand that it was likely I would have considered other airlines.  As I said in my question, my flight back to the US on United allowed me to select all seats without additional fee.  It was not something I expected to find, so didn't allow for it in my flight searches to start with.  I will in the future!  Booking 7 seats at one time I believe I could have reasonable expectation that those 7 seats are together...

Comment: @midavalo Both United and AA choose for "premium" seat selection, including those closer to the front of the aircraft.  The fact you didn't have to pay on United simply means that there were some non-"Premium" seats still available - probably helped by the fact that your flight was a little further away at the time.

Comment: @Midavalo - you're not a frequent traveller, this kind of unbundling (and especially how it affects families) has been in the news for over a year. As long as we sort for the least expensive flights and give companies like AA our money, they'll continue doing this. That said, you bought seats where the seat allocation was unbundled. Now you have to bundle it back in. As to your volume argument, it's like trying to get  free luggage or an economy plus upgrade because you bought seven seats, that's unfortunately not how it works.

Comment: "sympathetic check-in attendant to waive the fees"  There are NO fees for these seats at check-in.  This whole answer is far more of a rant than anything useful...

Comment: "and give companies like AA our money" - exactly, that is the problem. People should stop using companies that charge a full extra ticket just for parents to be able to sit with their own young children. This must really be a US thing, I have never experienced this kind of behavior anywhere else in the world. Once, flying on Swiss airlines, my two children (2 and 4) were put on isolated seats from me and my wife, but a simple request at check-in brought us all together. and since none but AA charges 100 dollars for aisle seats, other passengers would surely switch with us if need be.

Comment: it _IS_ a safety risk as well as a huge nuisance for the other passengers if young children are seated by themselves. It is also against the rules of several companies (e.g. KLM and AirFrance).

Comment: @bjorn You mean "people with young children should stop using companies ..." I don't have kids right now, so I'll buy whoever gets my ass where I want to go.

Answer (score 23):

As you get nearer to the day of the flight - especially once check-in opens - many of those paid seats will be available for free.  Of course, that also means that other passengers will likely be able to select them and you may still miss out on seats together.

Given that you are travelling with children I would suggest giving the airline a call and requesting that they allocate seats together at no charge.  Many airlines will do this to allow families to sit together, although there is no obligation to do so at this time (The US government is considering passing a law to require them to do this for young children, but it has not yet happened).

Otherwise your only options are to pay the fee for the seat selection, or wait until check-in or at the airport. I would suggest attempting to check-in as soon as possible after it is allowed (generally 24 hours before the flight) in order to increase your chances of being seated together.

Comment: Worst case scenario, there may be passengers travelling alone who would be willing to exchange seats; cabin crew are often very helpful in trying to arrange this once boarding is complete.

Comment: @Traveller - if you paid an extra $100 for that aisle seat, would you move to a middle seat?

Comment: @Traveller Even if the person didn't pay anything, very few people will exchange an aisle seat for a middle seat on a long-haul flight. Best not to bet on such an exchange.

Comment: @Voo I wrote ‘may’, not ‘will’. There are some considerate people out there!

Comment: In the past, when all seats in the same class were the same price (at least conceptually), it was easier to consider swapping because, hey we all paid the same price, we're all in the same boat.  Now that you have to explicitly pay for an aisle seat, it becomes a priced commodity and people are much much much less likely to be 'considerate' as  they made the conscious decision to pay the usurious fee for the aisle seat.

Comment: Being 'considerate' also really depends on the context. For an hour flight, sure, I'll sit really anywhere if it's going to make a material difference to someone else, and I've traded seats plenty of times to get families together. AKL-LAX is a 12 hour flight. Asking someone to take a middle seat for that is a pretty big ask, even more so if they already paid extra for the aisle seat.

Comment: @Traveller: Your asking them to do so would be utterly ridiculous. You do realize you'd be asking them to make give you their seat **AND** ~$100 of their money? I don't know about you but if someone with a family of 7 requested $100 from me on a 12h flight I would not only not feel "considerate", I would feel pissed off. This is despite the fact that I'd consider giving up my seat if they paid me that $100. (Which I could *still* quite fairly refuse to do, since at that point it's still an inconvenience on top of zero monetary benefit.)

Comment: Hey guys, it was just a comment, why all the angry-sounding replies?

Comment: @Traveller because you said ‘There are some considerate people out there!’, strongly implying that if you’re not willing to swap, you’re an inconsiderate person.

Comment: You are all assuming that I was referring to passengers who had paid the extra fee. On any flight there is surely likely to be at least a couple of lone travellers who didn’t, and may (possibly) be willing to swap. That’s all I meant by my comment. But I stand corrected :-)

Comment: Sure, somebody may be willing to swap, but it's very difficult to get people to swap to a worse seat (such as aisle to middle) on a 12 hour flight, particularly when you need enough swaps to get a family of seven reasonably together. Most people aren't that "considerate."

Comment: "Many airlines will do this to allow families to sit together, although there is no obligation to do so at this time (The US government is considering passing a law to require them to do this for young children, but it has not yet happened)." Really. Say I have a 4 year old kid, they might consider placing the kid somewhere else than next to me? That sounds rather ridiculous. I would ask them for the fun of having a long flight with a kid crying for his mommy and daddy. It should not be a law, it should be just common airline policy since a long time coming from common sense and decency.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider mixed strategies. It is important for the young child and parents to be together. I suggest paying to get a block of three seats including a window for them. If you are willing to risk scattered mid-row seats for the rest of the group, monitor the seat selection in case better choices become available closer to flight time. If not, plan to check them in as early as possible.

Comment: "It is important for the young child and parents to be together": important enough that the airline should ensure it without an extra fee.

Comment: @phoog It would be great if airlines always did what they "should" do.

Comment: An outraged parent might try pointing out that the liability for the consequences of the separate seating might fall on the airline.

Comment: @phoog That might get one parent near the youngest child. It could be in two middle seats, one behind the other, an arrangement they could get for free now.

Comment: +1 for "Mixed strategies"! Bonus points if we find the Nash equilibrium =P

Comment: @Mehrdad I strongly suspect that the current pricing of e.g. aisle seats is close to the Nash equilibrium, treating passengers collectively as one player. If it were not, the airlines would change the pricing, or the proportion of flyers who pay for them would change. The airlines have the resources and motivation to optimize their seat pricing strategy.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Hahhaha :)

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying that having made a number of intercontinental flights with nine children I can at least speak with a measure of experience.  I would not expect to get a block of seven seats without paying extra. As has been pointed out, that's how airlines make money nowadays.

I'm heading from Scotland to Australia in a few weeks. Because of time constraints I'm not able to fly on one of my favoured planes or with one of my favoured airlines.  I don't lie 777s so for the legs which will be flown in 777s I have paid extra to reserve a suitable aisle seat. On the other hand, for the feeder flight of about 2 hours, it's not worth it. And no, I wouldn't move from a seat for which I've paid a significant extra fee unless the airline were prepared to upgrade me to a different class.

I really don't see what the problem is in splitting up your party into groups -- it's never been any problem for us.  As long as the youngest of your children is with either a parent or an older sibling it should be just fine.  Or at least it's always worked out that way for us.